# Append zero to number if less than 10?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an int representing lives.

```
NSString* lifeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",lives];
```

However it outputs:

```
1
2
3
..
10
...
```

I need:

```
    01
    02
    03
    ..
    10
    ...
```

I know I can do this with an if statement, but I am wondering if NSString might have a clever way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Remember to look at the list of Related questions before posting your question. The first one listed would have answered your question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `%02d` as your format code to require a particular length (i.e. 2), and the left padding value of zero:

```
NSString* lifeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",lives];
```